# Do subgraphs imply non-planarity if they correspond to subdivisions of K3,2 and K5 graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

I was given this problem:
"Determine which of the graphs in figure 2 are planar.  In each case either draw a planar graph or exhibit a subgraph which is a subdivision of K3,3 or K5".  I did the first part using Euler's characteristic and found one to be planar and the other two to be non-planar.  The planar graph was of K3,2 form, so drawing it out was trivial.  However, I do not understand what is being asked of the nonplanar graphs.

I've given an example of one of the nonplanar graphs in the picture.  How can I tell whether a subgraph of it is a subdivision of K3,2 or K5? What exactly does that prove anyway? Is it that a graph is necessarily non-planar if a subgraph of K3,2 or K5 corresponds to one of its possible subgraphs?

By the way, don't feel obliged to use the example graph I have given if you can explain the concept with a simpler graph.

[image: sample graph]

Comment: Kuratowskis theorem states that any graph with a subdivion $K{3,3}$ or $K_5$ as a subgraph is nonplanar. Finding them is usually done by brute force in cases like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it that a graph is necessarily non-planar if a subgraph of $K3,2$ or $K5$ corresponds to one of its possible subgraphs?

The graphs $K_{3,3}$ (not $K_{3,2}$) and $K_5$ are non-planar.  If we subdivide the edges in a graph (essentially replacing edges with paths), we don't affect planarity.  So any subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ is non-planar.  Therefore, if $G$ is a graph that contains a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$, then $G$ is non-planar.

[Kuratowski's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem) is the converse: all non-planar graphs contain a subgraph that is a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.

(Note that $G$ might not contain a $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ subgraph, while still having a subgraph that is a subdivison of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$.)

The graph is the picture will not have a $K_{3,3}$ subdivision (as it does not have $\geq 6$ vertices of degree $\geq 3$).  However, it contains a $K_5$ subdivision induced by the vertices $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$.